# CGFloat Equatable failed for same values

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

[image]

```
let xCoordinate: CGFloat = 1.4
XCTAssertEqual(view.frame.origin.x, xCoordinate)
```

I got the following error while running a test, as shown in the screenshot:
`XCTAssertEqual failed: ("1.4") is not equal to ("1.4") -`

Does anyone have any solutions or explanations?

Answer (score 3):

If I am not making mistake take a look at this option of the evaluation of the `CGFloat`:

```
XCTAssertEqual(_, _, accuracy:)
```

In this case you could set accuracy to evaluate `CGFloat` numbers because evaluation of them without take in to account accuracy is not right.

Comment: It has been deprecated. We can use `XCTAssertEqual(_, _, accuracy:)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any solutions or explanations?

The solution is what Oleg has suggested. The explanation is that 1.4 is not expressible as a CGFloat. In normal decimals, you may have noticed that, unless the denominator of a fraction is only divisible by 2 or 5 (the factors of 10) when you try ti convert it to a decimal number, it goes on forever. eg. 1/3 is 0.33333333333...

The same applies to CGFloats except the number base is 2, not 10. 1.4 is 7/5. 5 is not divisible by 2, therefore if converted to a binary number, it would repeat forever. In fact, it would be 1.0110011...

So your `view.frame.origin.x` is likely to be a number close to 1.4 but not exactly 1.4  and your `xCoordinate` will be a different number very close to 1.4. These two numbers do not compare equal, but when rounded to say six decimal places to be printed, look like 1.4.